# How to find last occurrence of a substring in a given string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, substring

I have a string, which describe some word, I must change ending of it to "sd", if ending == "jk".
For an example, I have word: "lazer**jk**", I need to get from it "lazer**sd**".

I tried to use method .gsub!, but it doesn't work correctly if we have more than one occurrence of substring "jk" in a word.

Comment: "Last occurrence" or "ending"?

Answer (score 1):

[`String#rindex`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-rindex) returns the index of the last occurrence of the given substring

[`String#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) can take two integers arguments, first is index where start to replace and second - length of replaced string

You can use them this way:

```rb
replaced = "foo"
replacing = "booo"

string = "foo bar foo baz"
string[string.rindex(replaced), replaced.size] = replacing

string
# => "foo bar booo baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"jughjkjkjk\njk".sub(/jk$\z/, 'sd')
 => "jughjkjkjk\nsd"
```

without $ is probably sufficient.

Comment: Yes, you don't need $, so why have it there in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to replace a specific suffix only.  If so, I would probably suggest using `sub` along with an anchored regex (to check for the desired characters only at the end of the string):

```
string_1 = "lazerjk"
string_2 = "lazerjk\njk"
string_3 = "lazerjkr"

string_1.sub(/jk\z/, "sd")  
#=>  "lazersd"

string_2.sub(/jk\z/, "sd")  
#=>  "lazerjk\nsd"

string_3.sub(/jk\z/, "sd")
#=>  "lazerjkr"
```

Or, you could do without a regex at all by using the `reverse!` method along with a simple conditional statement to `sub!` only when the suffix is present:

```
string = "lazerjk"
old_suffix = "jk"
new_suffix = "sd"
string.reverse!.sub!(old_suffix.reverse, new_suffix.reverse).reverse! if string.end_with? (old_suffix)
string 
#=>  "lazersd"
```

OR, you could even use a *completely* different approach.  Here's an example using `chomp` to remove the unwanted suffix and then `ljust` to pad the desired suffix to the modified string.

```
string = "lazerjk"
string.chomp("jk").ljust(string.length, "sd")
#=>  "lazersd"
```

Note that the new suffix only gets added if the length of the string was modified with the initial chomp.  Otherwise, the string remains unchanged.

Comment: What's about `"lazerjk\njk"` or `"lazerjkr"` with such regexp?

Comment: Good point @mechnicov, I edited my post to include those examples and to use a more appropriate anchor.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to substitute the LAST OCCURRENCE (as opposed to suffix only), then this could be accomplished by using `sub` along with `reverse`:

```
string = "jklazerjkm"
old_substring = "jk"
new_substring = "sd"
string.reverse.sub(old_substring.reverse, new_substring.reverse).reverse
#=>  "jklazersdm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `"jk"` at the end of a string with something else is straightforward and can be addressed without concern for other instances of `"jk"` that may be in the string, so I assume that is not what is being asked. Rather, I assume the problem is to replace the last instance of `"jk"` in a string with `"sd"`.

Here are two solutions that make use of [String#sub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-sub) with a regular expression.

**Use a negative lookahead**

The idea here is to match `"jk"` provided it is not followed later in the string by another instance of `"jk"`.

```
"lajkz\nejkrjklm".sub(/jk(?!.*jk)/m, "sd")
  #=> "lajkz\nejkrsdlm"
```

**Capture the part of the string that precedes the last `"jk"`**

The match, if there is one, consists of the front of the string followed by the last `"jk"`, which is replaced by the captured string followed by `"sd"`.

```
"lajkz\nejkrjklm".sub(/\A(.*)jk/m) { $1 + "sd" }
  #=> "lajkz\nejkrsdlm"
```

The two regular expressions can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make them self-documenting. The first is the following.

```
/
jk    # match literal
(?!   # begin a negative lookahead
  .*  # match zero or more characters other than line terminators
  jk  # match literal
)     # end negative lookahead
/mx   # invoke multiline and free-spacing regex definition modes.
```

Multiline mode causes `.` to match any character, including a line terminator.

The second regular expression can be written as follows.

```
\A    # match the beginning of the string
(.*)  # match zero or more characters other than line terminators
      # and save the match to capture group 1
jk    # match literal
/mx   # invoke multiline and free-spacing regex definition modes.
```

Note that in both expressions `.*` is *greedy*, meaning that it will match as many characters as possible, including `"jk"` so long as other requirements of the expression are met, here that the last instance of `"jk"` in the string is matched.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution:

```
str = "jughjkjkjk\njk"
pattern = "jk"
replace_with = "sd"
str = str.reverse.sub(pattern.reverse, replace_with.reverse).reverse
```